# Removing gaps from rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a container with items having varying heights. I'm displaying them in columns of 5 and 3 items max per line. I tried the following implementation but there are huge gaps in the row that I can't seem to remove. How would I fix this?

```css
body {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.masonry {
  width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.cell {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div style="height: 180px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 240px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 520px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 120px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 240px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 332px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 143px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 306px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 514px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 232px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 361px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 234px" class="cell"></div>
  <div style="height: 318px" class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which gaps do you want to remove, the horizontal, vertical or both?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Vertical gaps

Comment: CSS grid cannot create masonry style layouts.

Comment: @connexo recommendation on what I should use?

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/ Amazing little tool that'll allow you to re-build your grids on the go! Check out the site for examples/demos

Comment: Or wait for https://caniuse.com/?search=masonry

Comment: @connexo this is not supported in all browsers unfortunately

Comment: Set `.cell`'s css to `margin: 0px 10px;` and set `.masonry`'s css `grid-row-gap: 0px;`

Comment: @devAR Read again *wait for....*

Answer (score 0):

I believe a structure like this with elements cover everywhere is what you need:
[image: example]

it can be achieved by `grid-area` or by using `grid-column-start`, `grid-column-end`, `grid-row-start`, and `grid-row-end` for each element based on how you want them to be positioned. 
you can read more about it [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/grid/)